# Is the Howey test pertaining to the source of profits or the receiving of profits?

Tags: united-states, new-jersey, securities, sec

The Howey test states:

"investment of money in a common enterprise with a reasonable expectation of profits to be derived from the efforts of others"

Is this "profits to be derived from the efforts of others" pertaining to the source of the money (imagine the money coming from people not including yourself thus from the efforts of others) or the receiving of profits (so it would mean the money source could be other people. As long as you yourself are NOT an active participant and are NOT showing some level of work to acquire the profits in some kind of work or competition of skill or luck regardless of the source of the money you're participating to acquire.)

Thank you.

Comment: Why can't it be both?

Comment: It would actually have to be both, right?  I had never heard of this test but just looked it up:  Seems clear enough that it identifies a transaction between two parties.  I.e. a source and a recipient.  You can’t have one without the other, so both are required.  (Caution - deep thinking may lead to over thinking…). ;)

Comment: @Rick I don't know but if it's the first one then that would mean that a competition in which you participate in some way would be illegal due to 1) investment of money. 2) into common Enterprise (any company or org) 3) reasonable expectation of profits (who knows what a "reasonable expectation" is? 4) from the efforts of others being the funds source.If it's the second one would mean basically someone else is competing for you to get something while you're hands off. As you can see this case law is pretty vague and confusing.

Comment: @MichaelHall I hear you but this specific rule has had various different interpretations since it's introduction. If it was clear cut I as a non lawyer wouldn't of been able to even interpret it the way I did. People have done to prison for YEARS for violating securities laws (in many cases unintentionally I am sure). I'd be very foolish to not interpret the laws and do legal research. I never thought I'd hear someone say "overthinking" in a law stack exchange. My question is about the source of "profits" not the recipient or organization parties. I'm out of chars but read my message  to Rick.

Comment: I made my comment before I read your other questions about on-line poker, but I don't see any parallel between investing in a business and participating in a competition or playing a game of chance for prize money.  You are not wrong for researching this if you are concerned for your personal situation and believe there is risk, I'm just offering an interpretation.

Comment: @MichaelHall Deep thinking leads to understanding. The law IS vague. If it wasn't real lawyers wouldn't of been interpreting this case law differently for years.  Also, there's even more ambiguity in this case law. What is a "reasonable expectation of profits?". Also, what if you have a game like a poker event but it was deemed the participation was directly for the expecting of profits due to how the advertising. Also the funds of the tournament are not your own efforts. Now: prongs 1, 2, 3 and 4 are met IF "derived" is tied to source of funds rather than action of receiving funds. See?

Comment: @MichaelHall the SEC has always looked at the purpose of the participant. Imagine "Pay $5 and enter this poker tournament where you can win $1m from the collective player prize pool!". If the participant is committing funds into poker tournament (prong 1) into common enterprise (tournament company) for "reasonable expectation of profit" which can be argued based on consumer advertising then the 4th prong "derived by the efforts of others" is important and cause you to be in trouble with the law for running a tournament. I'm just going by the letter of the law and trying to understand it.

Comment: I am unfamiliar with the practical application of the rule and simple took the question at face value, simplifying along the lines of "*does a 'transaction' apply to the buyer or the seller?*"  I'm quilty of underthinking some times, but there are also plenty of very naive questions on this site, so it can be difficult to discern the level of base knowledge or common sense sometimes.

Comment: @MichaelHall my question was about the profits and the fourth prong of the law. As you know lawyers tends to interpret and manipulate the laws and their application doesn't always match what a layman would interpret it as so I am looking for others perspectives. it's all good mate.

Comment: When you say (in your reply to my initial comment) "*in some way would be illegal*", do you mean like a [Ponzi scheme](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ponzi_scheme#:~:text=In%20a%20Ponzi%20scheme%2C%20a,the%20way%20it%20is%20described.)? Because if that's the way the return on investment is created then it would probably be unlawful i.e. fraud.

Comment: @Rick I mean a entry ticket into a poker competition would constitute a investment contract, and ultimately an illegal unregistered security if the law is based purely on source of funds. A Ponzi scheme is when you tell people "Hey, I will invest your money into real estate! Guaranteed 150% returns!" but you then pay the last investor with the money of the next investor. I don't we have enough details to talk about Ponzi schemes as we'd need a business model to talk about. I'm just asking about the laws regarding investment contracts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The *Howey* test is a test of what constitutes an "investment contract", which is a residual form of security subject to the federal Securities Act of 1933 and the federal Securities Exchange Act of 1934. There are also many *per se* securities which automatically qualify without analysis under that test.

An arrangement that merely constitutes active participation in self-employment is not a security, even if it flows from activities of others (like customers paying money) and even if you must invest some money (e.g. a buy-in price to become a partner in a law firm).

For example, if you take over a one man sole proprietorship landscaping business from its previous owner, the business purchased is not a security, because the business you are purchasing does not have you profiting from work done by other people, you seeking to make money from your own work.

But, if offered to pay the owner of the sole proprietorship landscaping business $100,000 in exchange for 50% of his future profits, without having to work in the business yourself, that would be an investment contract that constitutes a security, for purposes of federal securities laws, under *Howey*.